# Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling is very slow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, process, nsworkspace

I was using a technique described by apple for [Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2050/_index.html) to Observe Arbitrary Processes.

I used exact source code mentioned there and with all three techniques. But the response is very slow and sometimes even does not work.

Is there anything missing in documentation?

Comment: The last revision to that article is 2008... that's like 20 dog years. What kind of app are you writing (i.e. is it a GUI app or is it a daemon or agent)?  The NSWorkspace method should still be working, but it's been years since I've tried it and I see the notifications deliver some new information as of MacOS 10.6.

Comment: I am writing application which communicates to daemon about launch or close of arbitrary processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh... you gave me the keyword I was looking for. You want to monitor *processes*, not apps. You can't use the NSWorkspace solution if you are trying to catch non-AppKit apps or command line processes in addition to regular Macintosh apps.

Try focusing on the [kqueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html) solution.

And if that isn't good, look at "The Service-Oriented Alternative" section in your Apple Tech Note. If you rethink your approach a bit, you might be able to use launchd to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried NSWorkspace solution to catch Appkit apps. It's response time is terrible and unreliable. I also tried kqueue solution but it was not responsive. May be I am doing something wrong. I will give a try again.

Comment: Using kqueue, I am able manage close of process. But not the launch of process. Do you have any idea how kqueue can be used to manage launch event?